# Change placeholder value depending on body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small page where I swicth from one language to another by changing the body class: https://jsfiddle.net/3ddo465n/2/

```
<div class="en container">
  <p lang="en"> ... </p>
  <p lang="ru"> ... </p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Field name">
  </form>
</div>

.container.en [lang="ru"] {
  display: none;
}
.container.ru [lang="en"] {
  display: none;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot think of any way to change the form's input placeholder text with this approach without duplicating the input field (which won't be a valid HTML due to duplicating IDs). Any ideas?

Comment: why don't use JavaScript?

Comment: You could use jquery to change the language based on lang attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
   var placeHolder ={
      en: 'Field name',
      ru: 'Франции'
   }
   var lang = $(this).data("lang");
   $(".container").removeClass("en ru").addClass(lang);
   $(".container input").attr('placeholder', placeHolder[lang])
})
```

[There is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/3ddo465n/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work

```js
var placeEn = "Field name";
var placeRu = "Sorry i don't know";

$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
 var lang = $(this).data("lang");
  $(".container").removeClass("en ru").addClass(lang);
 if (lang == "ru"){
   $("input[type=text]").prop("placeholder",placeRu);
  } else{
   $("input[type=text]").prop("placeholder",placeEn);
  }
})
```

```css
.container.en [lang="ru"] {
  display: none;
}
.container.ru [lang="en"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-lang="en">En</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-lang="ru">Ru</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="en container">

  <p lang="en">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium libero aspernatur nihil eum saepe eligendi nobis eos rerum mollitia ex assumenda, tenetur eveniet facere facilis dicta harum explicabo similique ullam!
  </p>
  <p lang="ru">
    10 июня во Франции стартовал 15-й чемпионат Европы по футболу. Сборная России проиграла две встречи на групповом турнире — Словакии (1:2) и Уэльсу (0:3), а также сыграла вничью с Англией (1:1). В итоге команда Леонида Слуцкого досрочно отправилась домой.
    Турнир завершится 10 июля.
  </p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Field name">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery method [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change the placeholder text. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/3ddo465n/3/)

Below is an example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul > li > a").click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).data("lang");
    $(".container").removeClass("en ru").addClass(lang);

    if (lang == "en")
      $('input[type="text"]').attr('placeholder', 'Field name');
    else
      $('input[type="text"]').attr('placeholder', 'Russian text');
  })

});
```

```css
.container.en [lang="ru"] {
  display: none;
}
.container.ru [lang="en"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-lang="en">En</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-lang="ru">Ru</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="en container">
  <p lang="en">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium libero aspernatur nihil eum saepe eligendi nobis eos rerum mollitia ex assumenda, tenetur eveniet facere facilis dicta harum explicabo similique ullam!
  </p>
  <p lang="ru">
    10 июня во Франции стартовал 15-й чемпионат Европы по футболу. Сборная России проиграла две встречи на групповом турнире — Словакии (1:2) и Уэльсу (0:3), а также сыграла вничью с Англией (1:1). В итоге команда Леонида Слуцкого досрочно отправилась домой.
    Турнир завершится 10 июля.
  </p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Field name">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example code I made last time using jQuery. I believe this could help you in a way:

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js";

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('html').attr('lang') == 'en') {
        $('#intro').text('Hello World');
    }
    else if ( $('html').attr('lang') == 'cn') {
        $('#intro').text('你好，世界');
    }
});

<div id="intro"></div>
```

[image]
Just create a dropdown for your chosen language and based on that choice, just set the `lang` attribute to `cn`,`en`,etc.

Comment: Can you please replace the image with code? It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your solution copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image.